# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY when creating custom object WITH ModifyAll

Tags: custom-object, metadata-api

The Apex code is creating some custom object (NOT records, creating the custom object itself), but is only working when executed by admins. Otherwise, users get `INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY` - even when they have "API Enabled", "View All Data" and "Modify All Data" permissions.

Am I missing another permission to give? I went through the questions with the same error but none seem to match my scenario.

Comment: Can you check, Respective user have CRUD permissions on custom object related object

Comment: The custom object has no related object (except User for the default fields such as ownerId)

Comment: Have you verified the below troubleshooting steps? 1. Make sure whether the user have access to record ids of the lookup fields and/or master-detail fields in the record.
2. Check the user Profile(CRUD Permissions).
3. Profile need to have access for the record types.
4. Record's OwnerId automatically gets share record when the record is inserted. If the apex code try to create the same(Share record for the owner) explicitly. This error occurs.

Comment: 5. Check whether the apex code is trying to create share records to the record which the current user doesn't have access to it.
6. Check whether there are any hard-coded ids are miss matching the environments.

Comment: The Apex code is trying to create a custom object using the Metadata API. No records are created at this stage.

Comment: @user7094 most probably users dont have `Customize application` permission which is required to create custom object. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dev_objectcreate_task_lex.htm&type=5

Comment: @Shamina that was indeed what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: @user7094 good to know that worked for you. I've posted my comment as an answer

Comment: @user7094 could you accept the answer? This can also help others who may have similar question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `Customize application` is required to create custom object from the apex code.

**Note**: adding this permission to non-admin users, means that users will also be able to create custom object from UI setup menu in salesforce.

Reference from [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dev_objectcreate_task_lex.htm&type=5) :

> **USER PERMISSIONS NEEDED** To create and edit custom objects: Customize Application